Why the optimum solution of most optimization problems requires moderation?
I have seen a lot of optimization problems where our subject has a minimum or maximum value if we choose a moderate condition. Here are some examples:

A rectangle with a constant perimeter $P$ has the maximum area if the sides are equal to each other.

From polygons inscribed in a circle, the regular polygon has the largest area (see).

Area of a rectangle inscribed in a triangle is maximized if two adjacent vertices of the rectangle or on the midpoint of the sides of a triangle (see).


There are probably a lot of more examples of such optimization problems where the optimum solution is achieved if we select the moderate case (i.e. if we equalize some elements of the problem).  I'm wondering what is the secret of this recurring behavior?

In each of your examples, there are symmetries present in the statement of the problem. For example, regular polygons are almost certainly not optimal when inscribed in some random convex shape, but the circle has a lot of symmetry

To simplify the explanation, I'm going to assume we have a system with a single global maximum and no local maxima, but you can generalise without too much effort.
Suppose we are at the maximum of the system. Then if we move away from that point, in any direction, we must by necessity be moving to a location that is not the maximum, and hence we are moving to a point with a smaller objective value. Since this happens in every direction, the maximum must sit at some kind of balance point of the system. The reverse is also true - if we are at a balance point (i.e. one where moving in any direction changes the objective in a similar way), then we must be at a local optimum, and by our original assumption that means we're at the global optimum.
For certain kinds of system, this behaviour is described by one of the corollaries of Fermat's theorem of stationary points, which says that the extreme values of a differentiable function $f$ occur either on the boundary of its domain or at points where its derivative is undefined or zero.
If our system has some kind of innate symmetry to it, then the maximum must also respect that symmetry. For example, in the case of finding the rectangle of maximum area, we know that an $x \times y$ rectangle has the same area as a $y \times x$ one, in addition to having the same perimeter. Thus, if we start with a square and adjust the aspect ratio in any fashion, it doesn't matter if we stretch or squish it the area will change in the same way (either always getting bigger, or always getting smaller). As a result, the square is a balance point of the system and so must be an extremum - and it doesn't take too much work to show that for fixed perimeter it provides the maximum area.
The idea behind this is also the reason why stationary points are also called equilibria, from the Latin meaning "equal weight", i.e. the point where all of the forces or influences have an equal effect, resulting in balance.
With that said, if the symmetry is not so simple, then the equilibrium won't necessary involve a straightforward equality of values either. As a simple example, consider the case of trying to maximise the area of a field bounded by a given length of fence and a fixed wall. In this case, if the field has width $y$ along the direction of the wall and length $x$ perpendicular to it, then you have an area of $x \times y$ but the length of fence is $L = 2x + y$ (as opposed to $L = 2x + 2y$ when you have to use the fence for all 4 sides rather than just 3) so the optimum occurs when $x = \frac{L}{4}$ and $y = \frac{L}{2}$, which are clearly not equal (but they do have an equal "influence" on the amount of fence used, if you can think of it that way).
